# Are DPI control buttons considered cheating for e-sports tournaments?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse, competitive-gaming, gaming-accessories

I've been using the [ROG Gladius II.](https://rog.asus.com/in/mice-mouse-pads/mice/ergonomic-right-handed/rog-gladius-ii-model/gallery/) gaming mouse for quite a while, which has a thumb mouse button on the bottom left side. When held, this reduces the dpi to 400, and when released, changes it back to 1200.

I've been using this feature all the time while playing CS:GO (casually), as it makes it really easy for me to aim & snipe with precision. But I've recently read about someone getting banned on DOTA for using programmable buttons.

So, are DPI control buttons disallowed in pro-level or e-sport competitions? Is it considered to be cheating to be using this button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each tournament and competition will have rules specifying what is allowed and what is not.

In the more serious competitions, you do not even use your own hardware.

Comment: In the case of Overwatch League, most players appear to have different keyboards. I'm sure there's an accepted list of devices, rather than a tournament providing hardware.

Comment: Or you have to submit the devices for inspection. It's not hard to add a USB loader into a keyboard so that it loads cheats. With some of the prizes, I wouldn't be surprised if people do try to cheat. In actuality, they may allow you to specify which keyboard you want, but the tournament organizers buy a new one to prevent modification. That would be pretty easy to arrange for and they may get the keyboards for really cheap or even free.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in high-level competition (like The International for Dota 2, or the LCS for League of Legends) teams will need to provide sealed peripherals to the tournament (or let them know which ones they'd like to use) and those peripherals are inventoried by the staff of the tournament itself. These peripherals are held under lock and key, and in the event of damage or disfunction, another one is unwrapped and used.

This prevents people for using cheats embedded in the peripherals themselves, and also allows for teams to have sponsor-friendly peripherals for their own use.

I've worked with esports teams in the past, and players are *very* particular about their settings being similar to the ones they practice on, and use at home. Things like DPI, sensitivity or the texture of their mousepads are important for them to compete at the highest level consistently.

Usually the tournament itself will have an approved list of vendors/brands they use, or it'll be worked out between the team's management and the organizers. Generally, if the mouse can be customized by a first-party solution (ie, downloading Logitech G Hub or whatever to customize Logitech peripherals) it'll be allowed.

Also, in a lot of cases each player is given their own SSD, and they're swapped in and out depending on who's playing; again, these are inventoried and stored by the tournament itself after the match is played. This allows for a consistent setting over the tournament, and also allows things to be audited if they need to be. Generally players aren't allowed phones or outside devices on the set, and that allows for security against sneaky USB keys, etc.

Answer (score -6):

This does not cause a disadvantage to the rivals, therefore it is allowed. In competitions it is forbidden. As long as you do not participate in tournaments, you can use it.